# For my specific purpose (1 mic, hiphop vocals only), will one of these preamps give a better sound?

Tags: audio-recording, audio, audio-interfaces, preamp

Looking at the new Presonus Quantum 2 at $700. Since I'm just using one mic (TLM 102) and laying down vocals, is there an advantage to getting that over their lower end modals, such as their Studio 6|8 at $300 or even the Studio 2|6 USB at $200?

Basically, is the preamp inside and the converters inside of each model going to give me the same quality signal? Is the extra price on the Quantum 2 for features that I won't use, such as extra inputs? Or is the actual sound quality going to be better.

Answer (score 0):

The following was discussed in a Sound On Sound review here:

https://www.soundonsound.com/reviews/presonus-quantum

> The Studio 192 already offered better-than-decent audio performance,
>   but the Quantum uses even more highly-specified converters and thus
>   improves on this in most respects.

I assume this would be the same quality improvement over the Presonus 'Studio' models that you mention as well.